# What is the constraint in this LaGrange Multipliers ??

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers where satisfied the equation $x^2+y^2+xy-3x-3y-9=0$

Find the max. and min. values of $x^2+y^2$

I don't know how to find the constraint

Comment: the constraint is you're confined to the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ cut out by $x^2 + y^2 + xy - 3x - 3y - 9 = 0$

Comment: Ok, next time i will do this

Comment: You should consider accepting the answers to some of your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint is the curve $$x^2+y^2+xy-3x-3y-9=0$$ Hence, you need to consider the function $$f(x,y; \lambda) = x^2 + y^2 + \lambda (x^2+y^2+xy-3x-3y-9)$$ and differentiate with respect to $x,y$ and $\lambda$ and find the critical points.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot